# How to Implement In-App Purchases in Windows 10 Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-rt

I want to integrate in-app purchasing in my windows universal app. I do the following thing before coding.

- Make App on [Windows Dev Center](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/dashboard/)
- Add products with details in IAPs section and submit to Store as you can see in [Image](https://cloudup.com/cvpVT8d9pxK)
- After that I use the following code in my app to get list of products of In-App purchasing and button to purchase product. I also used `CurrentApp` instead of `CurrentAppSimulator` in my code but it goes in exception.

```
private async void RenderStoreItems()
    {
        picItems.Clear();

        try
        {
            //StoreManager mySM = new StoreManager();
            ListingInformation li = await CurrentAppSimulator.LoadListingInformationAsync();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(li);

            foreach (string key in li.ProductListings.Keys)
            {
                ProductListing pListing = li.ProductListings[key];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(key);

                string status = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive ? "Purchased" : pListing.FormattedPrice;

                string imageLink = string.Empty;

                picItems.Add(
                    new ProductItem
                    {
                        imgLink = key.Equals("BaazarMagzine101") ? "block-ads.png" : "block-ads.png",
                        Name = pListing.Name,
                        Status = status,
                        key = key,
                        BuyNowButtonVisible = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive ? false : true
                    }
                );
            }

            pics.ItemsSource = picItems;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private async void ButtonBuyNow_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;

        string key = btn.Tag.ToString();

        if (!CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive)
        {
            ListingInformation li = await CurrentAppSimulator.LoadListingInformationAsync();
            string pID = li.ProductListings[key].ProductId;

            string receipt = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(pID, true);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(receipt);

            // RenderStoreItems();
        }
    }
```

I also Associate my app with Store and my app package is same as in MS Dev Center App as you can see in [Image](https://cloudup.com/ca4g4-WZY_x)

When I run my app and click on Buy button, I got this dialogue box as you can see in [Image](https://cloudup.com/cqLTzfNPYzi) after that I did not get receipt data from Store.

If I'm doing wrong then Please give me proper guide to implement the In-app purchase and test that In-app purchase in my laptop device.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue and the problem was in the `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` file.

### Solution in short

By default in the `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` the `IsTrial` is set to true and in that mode in-app purchases do not seem to work. When I changed it to false it started to work for me.

### Solution a little bit longer

- So first of all here we are talking about the simulation of an In-App Purchase in development time (by using the `CurrentAppSimulator` class). In that case you need a `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` file. It’s described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx)
- Now the window you showed is opened by the `CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync` line. It basically controls the return value of a Windows Runtime native method (which is very strange for me… I think it’s not intentional by Microsoft… something else should be done there), but if you let it return `S_OK` that basically is the case when the user paid for the in-App Purchase.

  [image: Screenshot of purchase simulation window]
- When it returns nothing then with very high probability something in the `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` is wrong. I suggest you to create your own `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` and read it with the `CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync` method like this:

  ```
  var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Testing\WindowsStoreProxy.xml");
  await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(file);
  ```
- For me using the default one from `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<app package folder>\LocalState\Microsoft\Windows Store\ApiData\WindowsStoreProxy.xml`
  did not work, but a single change already solved the problem: I changed this part

  ```
  <LicenseInformation>
          <App>
              <IsActive>true</IsActive>
              <IsTrial>true</IsTrial>
          </App>
  </LicenseInformation>
  ```

  To this:

  ```
  <LicenseInformation>
          <App>
              <IsActive>true</IsActive>
              <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
          </App>
  </LicenseInformation>
  ```

  (So `IsTrial` was set to false...)
- Now at this point I also would like to mention that this was a little bit strange, since in in the default `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` there was no Product defined for my In-App Purchase. So for my “RemoveAds” a proper `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` would be something like this:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
  <CurrentApp>
      <ListingInformation>
          <App>
              <AppId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</AppId>
              <LinkUri>http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</LinkUri>
              <CurrentMarket>en-US</CurrentMarket>
              <AgeRating>3</AgeRating>
              <MarketData xml:lang="en-US">
                  <Name>AppName</Name>
                  <Description>AppDescription</Description>
                  <Price>1.00</Price>
                  <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
                  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              </MarketData>
          </App>
          <Product ProductId="RemoveAds" LicenseDuration="1" ProductType="Durable">
              <MarketData xml:lang="en-US">
                  <Name>RemoveAds</Name>
                  <Price>1.00</Price>
                  <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
                  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              </MarketData>
          </Product>      
      </ListingInformation>
      <LicenseInformation>
          <App>
              <IsActive>true</IsActive>
              <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
          </App>
          <Product ProductId="1">
              <IsActive>true</IsActive>
          </Product>
      </LicenseInformation>
      <ConsumableInformation>
          <Product ProductId="RemoveAds" TransactionId="10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Status="Active" />
      </ConsumableInformation>
  </CurrentApp>
  ```
- Another thing I would like to point out is that the `CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync` with two parameter is obsolete. Leave the true parameter out and you get  `PurchaseResults` instance as the result, which contains the receipt in the `ReceiptXML` property.

Comment: this is a bit weird. does that mean that if we set trial in the store we cant use in app purchases?

Answer (score 0):

WindowsStoreProxy.xml to c# code and serialize to xml file

```
public static CurrentApp LoadCurrentApp(string productKey = "Premium", bool isActive = false, bool isTrial = false)
    {
        CurrentApp currentApp = new CurrentApp();
        currentApp.ListingInformation = new ListingInformation()
        {
            App = new App()
            {
                AgeRating = "3",
                AppId = BasicAppInfo.AppId,
                CurrentMarket = "en-us",
                LinkUri = "",
                MarketData = new MarketData()
                {
                    Name = "In-app purchases",
                    Description = "AppDescription",
                    Price = "5.99",
                    CurrencySymbol = "$",
                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                }
            },
            Product = new Product()
            {
                ProductId = productKey,
                MarketData = new MarketData()
                {
                    Lang = "en-us",
                    Name = productKey,
                    Description = "AppDescription",
                    Price = "5.99",
                    CurrencySymbol = "$",
                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                }
            }
        };
        currentApp.LicenseInformation = new LicenseInformation()
        {
            App = new App()
            {
                IsActive = isActive.ToString(),
                IsTrial = isTrial.ToString(),
            },
            Product = new Product()
            {
                ProductId = productKey,
                IsActive = isActive.ToString(),
            }
        };
        return currentApp;
    }
```

Base xml model

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MarketData")]
public class MarketData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CurrencySymbol")]
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CurrencyCode")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "App")]
public class App
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AppId")]
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LinkUri")]
    public string LinkUri { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CurrentMarket")]
    public string CurrentMarket { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AgeRating")]
    public string AgeRating { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MarketData")]
    public MarketData MarketData { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsActive")]
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsTrial")]
    public string IsTrial { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MarketData")]
    public MarketData MarketData { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ProductId")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsActive")]
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ListingInformation")]
public class ListingInformation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "App")]
    public App App { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "LicenseInformation")]
public class LicenseInformation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "App")]
    public App App { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CurrentApp")]
public class CurrentApp
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ListingInformation")]
    public ListingInformation ListingInformation { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LicenseInformation")]
    public LicenseInformation LicenseInformation { get; set; }
}
```

Get XmlFile

```
public async static Task<StorageFile> GetWindowsStoreProxyXmlAsync(string productKey, bool isActive = false, bool isTrial = false)
    {
        StorageFile xmlFile = null;
        var currentApp = LoadCurrentApp(productKey, isActive, isTrial);
        var xml = StorageHelper.SerializeToXML<CurrentApp>(currentApp);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            xmlFile = await StorageHelper.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("MarketData.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(xmlFile, xml);
        }
        return xmlFile;
    }
```