# UWP/WinRT: App stopped working after November update

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have a Universal Windows Platform app that was working fine. My development machine is running Windows 10, and after the Windows 10 November Update (1511, build 10586), the development version built by Visual Studio has stopped working. I was actually running this day-to-day as a standalone app, and I noticed this problem when after the update the app started immediately closing after the splash screen.

I uninstalled the development version of my app and installed the store version, and that works fine, even though no code has changed between the two versions. I updated Visual Studio to Update 1, and it still doesn't work. I've fully uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio but that didn't help either. I've also tried changing the Project Properties to target platform version 10.0.10586.0 and rebuilding, but that also doesn't seem to help.

This occurs on both Release and Debug builds, and on both x86 and x64.

On launch, it gets as far as the splash screen before informing me that I've triggered a breakpoint. The breakpoint was not set by me, but rather is in KernelBase.dll, and no source is available.

If I hit Continue, then I get an `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC4C431F08 (KernelBase.dll)`. The body of the error is:

> 0x00000004: The system cannot open the file (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80004005, 0x0000000000000005).

Hitting Continue again will get me into my code, which dies with:

> Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x000000C1517FAF50. HRESULT:0x802B000A The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Any ideas on what happened and how to correct?

Comment: Good luck with this. I also have an issue with the upgrade (different than yours though). The way I tracked it down was to start commenting out startup code until my app worked. FWIW my issue is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364580/wp8-1-and-wp10-differences#comment56496130_34364580). I'll note that in my case, the cause of the problem is known but the solution is yet to be known.